# Weird MySQL SELECT WHERE IN problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM library WHERE $cat IN (tags);
```

Say that I have `$cat = '15';` and `tags` is a fieldname in `library` that looks like this: `2,15,34, 45` 
How can I get it to work? I understand that normally the $var should be after the IN ($var), but the imploded array sits in my DB and not in the $var - somehow I've gotten it the wrong way around and I just cannot figure it out - Please help me, I'm wasting days :)

Comment: That's not MySQL problem, but yours.

Comment: Consider to normalize your table instead of using find_in_set()

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/mysql-find-in-set-vs-in).  `IN` does not work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` instead, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM library
WHERE FIND_IN_SET($cat, tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

select * from library where tags like '%,$cat,%';

Comment: This doesn't work when the required tag is at the start or the end of the list.

Comment: You can use this trick to get around it: `CONCAT(',',tags,',') LIKE '%,$cat,%'`, but in MySQL, `FIND_IN_SET` is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Would you not do:

```
SELECT * FROM library WHERE tags = $cat
```