# PHP How to tell if a string contains a certain value

Tags: php

In my SQL database I have a query that turns values in multiple rows into a single concatenated string.

```
id    |    image_filename    |    slides    |    languages    |    types
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
10    |    filename.jpg      |    55,4     |        1         |    TN,CQ
```

In PHP I am trying to check to see which slides this image is associated with.  If it is associated, that checkbox will be checked.

```
$isChecked = (strpos($slide,"5") !== false) ? " checked=\"checked\"" : "";
```

The problem is that the statement above will return true because there is a 5 contained in there.  What needs to happen is it will return **false** because 5 does not equal 55.

How can I create something in PHP to check the values before each comma, and see if it matches a certain string that I can specify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the actual values conjoined by the comma!

```
$isChecked = in_array("5",explode(",",$slide))!=false?" checked=\"checked\"":"";
```

See [explode](http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=explode&lang=en&scope=quickref).

Edit: Just noticed you only want to check the value BEFORE the comma only. This will actually be faster than creating an array from the string:

```
$isChecked = "5"==strstr($slide,',',true)?" checked=\"checked\"":"";
```

Assuming you have PHP 5.3+. See [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Answer (score 3):

You should `explode($slide)` then convert to integers

```
$parts = explode(',', $slide);
if(intval($parts[0]) == 55) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Upvote for not missing the "before the comma" part of the post, although the integer conversion isn't necessarily necessary. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should actually use the MySQL `FIND_IN_SET()` function to do this reliably at the RDBMS level. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in), whose answer illustrates your goal.