# Strange GROUP_CONCAT behaviour in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I ran into a really strange problem today when using the MySQL function `GROUP_CONCAT`:

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM order WHERE customer_id='X' AND order_status_id IN ((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(order_status_id SEPARATOR ',') FROM order_status WHERE profit='1'))
```

but that returns NULLL, however:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM order WHERE customer_id='X' AND order_status_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

this works as well as the first query to concat the status id's, grouped however they return NULL as total

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` returns a string, which is a single value. The `IN()` clause, although it accepts a comma-separated list of values, won't take just *any* string you give it and then parse out the individual values.

It treats the result of the `GROUP_CONCAT()` as a single string unit, which could be a member of many other strings in a comma-separated list, but no rows match `order_status_id = '1,3,5,6'`, which is what the RDBMS ultimately sees.

If you want to use a query for that `IN()` clause, use a subquery.  The `IN ()` clause knows how to deal with the rowset returned by the subquery and will treat it appropriately.

```
SELECT
  SUM(total) 
FROM order 
WHERE 
  customer_id='X' 
  AND order_status_id IN (
    SELECT order_status_id FROM order_status WHERE profit = '1'
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

About your question. Try to use FIND_IN_SET function -

```
SELECT
  SUM(total)
FROM
  `order`
WHERE
  customer_id='X' AND
  FIND_IN_SET(
    order_status_id,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(order_status_id) FROM order_status WHERE profit='1')
  )
```

I'd suggest you to use JOIN clause. For example -

```
SELECT o.* FROM `order` o
  JOIN order_status os
    ON o.order_status_id = os.order_status_id
WHERE o.customer_id='X' AND os.profit = 1
```

...then add aggregate functions you need.