# How Can I Write an SQL Query for the Contents of a Cell Array?

Tags: sql, matlab

Apologies if this should be fairly obvious! If I have a cell array of keys - how should I best query these against a database?

For example if I have the cell array:

```
Names = { 'Jon', 'Peter', 'Paul' };
```

Do I have to write the SQL in the form:

```
select *
from x
where name = 'Jon' or name = 'Peter' or name = 'Paul';
```

Or is there some way of writing it of the form:

```
select *
from x
where name = {Names};
```

Whilst I can write a function to generate the where clause, this feels far from ideal!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM   x
WHERE  name IN ('Jon', 'Peter', 'Paul')
```

Comment: Can in take a cell array rather than a string? I want to generate the queries based on they contents of the array (which are not constant).

Comment: read this, [*FIND_IN_SET*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least 2 ways:

In the where clause you could use: 
"in ('Jon','Peter')"

Or if you have the names you want to query in a table just use
"where names in (Select Name from [table with names])"

Hope that helps.