# Anyone can explain behind this logic in MySQL IN clause

Tags: mysql

Anyone can explain behind this logic in MySQL IN clause and help me understand this issue

I have a user table and this table users are belongs to one or many groups.
The group table primary key reference is updated in users table by comma(,) separated values as follows

```
Query 1. SELECT * FROM user;
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name | user_email              | group_id  |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
|       1 | suresh    | xxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com     | 22        |
|       2 | sundar    | s7sundera@gmail.com     | 2         |
|       3 | tester    | xxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com | 1,2,3,4   |
|       4 | gail      | zzzzzz@gmail.com        | 1,2,3,4,5 |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
```

If I use IN clause and group id value as 2 in MySQL I got only one result

```
Query 2. SELECT * FROM user WHERE group_id IN(2)
+---------+-----------+---------------------+----------+
| user_id | user_name | user_email          | group_id |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+----------+
|       2 | sundar    | s7sundera@gmail.com | 2        |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+----------+
```

If I use IN clause and group id value as (1,2) in MySQL I got three results

```
Query 3. SELECT * FROM user WHERE group_id IN(1,2)
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name | user_email              | group_id  |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
|       2 | sundar    | s7sundera@gmail.com     | 2         |
|       3 | tester    | xxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com | 1,2,3,4   |
|       4 | gail      | zzzzzz@gmail.com        | 1,2,3,4,5 |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
```

I want to get group id 2 users like following output but it is not working as expected

If I use this query I need to get query 3 results is it possible?

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE group_id IN(2)
```

Comment: I hate to break this to you but your design is wrong for the feature you devised.

Comment: Break group_id off into a mapping table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too long to be a comment, but you need to reconsider your current table design.  You should not be storing the `group_id` values as a comma separated list.

Your tables should be structured similar to the following:

```
create table user
(
    user_id int,  PK
    user_name varchar(50),
    user_email varchar(100)
);

create table groups
(
    group_id int, PK
    group_name varchar(10)
);

create table user_group
(
    user_id int,
    group_id int
);
```

The `user_group` table will have a Primary Key of both the `user_id` and the `group_id` so you cannot get duplicates and then these columns should be foreign keys to the respective tables.  This table will allow you to have multiple groups for each user_id.

Then when you query your tables, the query will be:

```
select u.user_id, 
  u.user_name,
  u.user_email,
  g.group_id
from user u
inner join user_group ug 
  on u.user_id = ug.user_id
inner join groups g
  on ug.group_id = g.group_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98dcf/1).

If you needed to for display purposes show the `group_id` values in a comma separated list, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
select u.user_id, 
  u.user_name,
  u.user_email,
  group_concat(g.group_id order by g.group_id) group_id
from user u
inner join user_group ug 
  on u.user_id = ug.user_id
inner join groups g
  on ug.group_id = g.group_id
group by u.user_id, u.user_name, u.user_email
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98dcf/3)

If you redesign your tables, then when you search it becomes much easier:

```
select u.user_id, 
  u.user_name,
  u.user_email,
  g.group_id
from user u
inner join user_group ug 
  on u.user_id = ug.user_id
inner join groups g
  on ug.group_id = g.group_id
where g.group_id in (1, 2)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98dcf/4)

Comment: This will sounds me clear to understanding the logic. But is it possible to achieve my expectation using any mysql inbuild functions.

Comment: @Sundar You would have to use `FIND_IN_SET` but if possible, you are better off redesigning your tables.

Comment: +1 because this is the correct way to store multiple values for a single column! :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's why I said in the beginning it was too long for a comment.  I only hope they can change the design otherwise it will just lead to more headaches for them. :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat this table structure is more comfortable for me in query performance if i normalize this structure the i have to join mapping table and have to do group by option. I need this comma(,) separated values in many places in project so each time i have to generate this comma separate values using GROUP_CONCAT. So i keep this comma separated as it is and generate one more mapping table it's too good for me.

Comment: @Sundar: Whatever works for you, just know that searching a comma separated list in MySQL is *very* inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

When passing `1,2` to the `IN` operator, you're asking for `1` and `2`; this is why it will return all three results. If you have a column with comma separated values, you're violating normal form; as each column should not contain more than one value. If you want to find a single value in a multi-valued comma separated column, then you can use `FIND_IN_SET`.

A normalized schema would look like:

```
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+
| user_id | user_name | user_email              |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+
|       2 | sundar    | s7sundera@gmail.com     |
|       3 | tester    | xxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com |
|       4 | gail      | zzzzzz@gmail.com        |
+---------+-----------+-------------------------+

+---------+-----------+
| user_id | group_id  |
+---------+-----------+
|       2 | 2         |
|       3 | 1         |
|       3 | 2         |
|       3 | 3         |
|       3 | 4         |
|       4 | 1         |
|       4 | 2         |
|       4 | 3         |
|       4 | 4         |
|       4 | 5         |
+---------+-----------+

+----------+
| group_id |
+----------+
|        1 |
|        2 |
|        3 |
|        4 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sometimes I need to search two groups in this case FIND_IN_SET won't work like " SELECT * FROM user WHERE group_id FIND_IN_SET('2,3', group_id);" It is yielding empty result set

Comment: @Sundar I would recommend that you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in)

Comment: @Sundar `FIND_IN_SET` returns you a boolean, you don't do `group_id FIND_IN_SET()`.  To search for multiple values, you need OR.  `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, group_id) OR FIND_IN_SET(3, group_id);`  Though storing comma separated lists in MySQL is a bad idea, I suggest using the "link table" instead.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk: `IN(1,2)` is returning three rows because each row is being converted to an `INT`, which means each row is becoming the first value in the list.  Those three rows are the ones that start with `1` OR `2`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I like your explanation much better.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk: I only know that because of a question I asked (which you linked to ^_^) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in

Comment: @RocketHazmat Let me +1 that too!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't treat comma separated lists as anything more than just a string.  When you do `WHERE group_id IN(2)`, it converts `group_id` to an `INT`, so it can compare it with `2`.

When casting to an `INT`, MySQL stops at the first non-number character.

For example, `'1,2,3,4,5' IN (2)` becomes `1 IN (2)`.  Which is FALSE.

You can try to use `FIND_IN_SET` to do what you want, but it's not very efficient (because it can't use indexes; it need to read *every single row* to see if it matches).

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, group_id)
```

To search for multiple rows, use `OR`.

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, group_id) OR FIND_IN_SET(2, group_id)
```

The *correct* way to do this, is to create a "link table" that contains one (or more) rows for each user, showing what group(s) they are in.

Comment: @ChrisTravers: I only know this because I had a *similar* issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4155873/206403

Answer (score 1):

## EXPLANATION

What is the logic of the query `SELECT * FROM user WHERE group_id IN(1,2);` ?

- You gave a list of numbers `(1,2)`
- The `groud_id` was being compare numerically
- Anything that numerically matched 1 or 2 up to the first comma came up as a result

## SUGGESTION

What I am about to present to you may seem rather unorthodox but please follow me...

Here is the query that will get every row that has both 1 and 2 in group_ids:

```
SELECT user.* FROM
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,CONCAT(',',group_id ,',') group_ids
FROM user) U WHERE LOCATE(',2,',group_ids)) U1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,CONCAT(',',group_id ,',') group_ids
FROM user) U WHERE LOCATE(',4,',group_ids)) U2
ON U1.id = U2.id
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = U2.id;
```

Here is the code create our sample data

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS sundar;
CREATE DATABASE sundar;
use sundar
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    user_name VARCHAR(30),
    user_email VARCHAR(70),
    group_id VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO user (user_name,user_email,group_id) VALUES
('suresh' , 'xxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com'     ,'22'),
('sundar' , 's7sundera@gmail.com'     ,'2'),
('tester' , 'xxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com' ,'1,2,3,4'),
('gail'   , 'zzzzzz@gmail.com'        ,'1,2,3,4,5');
SELECT * FROM user;
```

Let's create your sample

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS sundar;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE sundar;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use sundar
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE user
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     user_name VARCHAR(30),
    ->     user_email VARCHAR(70),
    ->     group_id VARCHAR(128),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO user (user_name,user_email,group_id) VALUES
    -> ('suresh' , 'xxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com'     ,'22'),
    -> ('sundar' , 's7sundera@gmail.com'     ,'2'),
    -> ('tester' , 'xxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com' ,'1,2,3,4'),
    -> ('gail'   , 'zzzzzz@gmail.com'        ,'1,2,3,4,5');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

and here is what it looks like

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM user;
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
| id | user_name | user_email              | group_id  |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | suresh    | xxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com     | 22        |
|  2 | sundar    | s7sundera@gmail.com     | 2         |
|  3 | tester    | xxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com | 1,2,3,4   |
|  4 | gail      | zzzzzz@gmail.com        | 1,2,3,4,5 |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Again, here is the messy query that will get what you want:

```
SELECT user.* FROM
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,CONCAT(',',group_id ,',') group_ids
FROM user) U WHERE LOCATE(',1,',group_ids)) U1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,CONCAT(',',group_id ,',') group_ids
FROM user) U WHERE LOCATE(',2,',group_ids)) U2
ON U1.id = U2.id
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = U2.id;
```

Here it is executed:

```
mysql> SELECT user.* FROM
    -> (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,CONCAT(',',group_id ,',') group_ids
    -> FROM user) U WHERE LOCATE(',1,',group_ids)) U1
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,CONCAT(',',group_id ,',') group_ids
    -> FROM user) U WHERE LOCATE(',2,',group_ids)) U2
    -> ON U1.id = U2.id
    -> INNER JOIN user ON user.id = U2.id;
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
| id | user_name | user_email              | group_id  |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
|  3 | tester    | xxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com | 1,2,3,4   |
|  4 | gail      | zzzzzz@gmail.com        | 1,2,3,4,5 |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK, how about looking for `(2,4)` ?

```
mysql> SELECT user.* FROM
    -> (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,CONCAT(',',group_id ,',') group_ids
    -> FROM user) U WHERE LOCATE(',2,',group_ids)) U1
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,CONCAT(',',group_id ,',') group_ids
    -> FROM user) U WHERE LOCATE(',4,',group_ids)) U2
    -> ON U1.id = U2.id
    -> INNER JOIN user ON user.id = U2.id;
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
| id | user_name | user_email              | group_id  |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
|  3 | tester    | xxxxxxxx@yyyyyyyyyy.com | 1,2,3,4   |
|  4 | gail      | zzzzzz@gmail.com        | 1,2,3,4,5 |
+----+-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Looks like it works.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Yeah it's too good and different until consider query performance issues