# group mysql count values in comma separated field

Tags: mysql, count

I have a users table with columns: `user_id, mechanic_id`

and

mechanics table with `id`

I would like to count how many users have the same mechanic.

Users table

```
+-------------------------+
| user_Id   mechanic_id   |
+-------------------------+
| 1           1,2         |
| 2           2,1         |
| 3           2,1,8,16    |
| 4           1,16,3      |
+-------------------------+
```

mechanics table

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
  ...
```

Count for $id1 is: 4

Count for $id2 is: 3

Count for $id3 is: 1

Count for $id8 is: 1

Count for $id16 is: 2

Comment: Why are you storing data as a comma-separated list?  You should seriously consider normalizing your table.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in

Comment: blufeet - I need it in this way

Comment: @SašoKrajnc You're shooting yourself in the foot. You're violating the basic principles of database normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I am violating the basic principles of database normalization...Each user has  usually one mechanic or max 2 or 3, so that's why I decided to store data in users table.

I found solution based on @Marc B:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users a 
INNER JOIN mechanics b 
ON (FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.mechanic_id) > 0)
WHERE b.id = '{$id}' 
group by b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution: scrap this table design and rebuild with a properly normalized once. Then a simple join + group by + count query will work.

Worst solution: use MySQL's [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT mechanics.id, COUNT(user_ID)
FROM mechanics
LEFT JOIN users ON (FIND_IN_SET(mechanics.id, users.mechanic_id) > 0)
GROUP BY mechanics.id
```

Comment: I combined your solution with mine and it is working...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COUNT(user_Id)
FROM    users, mechanics
WHERE   mechanics.id IN (users.mechanic_id)
```