# IN string MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in my database this table :

```
+----+-----------+
| ID |    JOB    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Developer |
|  2 | Designer  |
+----+-----------+
```

I want to run this query that's normaly will get the **ID : 2**

```
select j.ID from jobs j where 'Designer' in ( j.JOBS )
```

unfortunately it's not working when I have like this table

```
+----+------------------------------------------+
| ID |                   JOB                    |
+----+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Developer                                |
|  2 | Designer,administrator,analyst,Developer |
+----+------------------------------------------+
```

Because the value of j.JOBS is string : **' Designer,administrator,analyst,Developer '**

not like multipe values separeted by commat like this : **' Designer ', ' administrator ' , ' analyst ' ,' Developer'**

So, how can I solve this problem, and I wish I explain well my question .thanks

Comment: First off, *don't* store multiple values in one field.  Normalize your data, and make a link table.  Second, if you *must* do it this way, use `FIND_IN_SET('Designer', j.JOBS)` (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in).

Comment: Rocket Hazmaz is right. You should have a job table (with only single job in job column), a people table and a people_job join table.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks. yes I know I have to use links between tables, but in my case I must store multipe values in one fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider your troubles to be punishment for storing a list of values in a single column.  You should have a separate table with one row per `id` and one row per `job`.  No lists in a row.  Just one item per row in an association table.

The answer to your question, though, is `find_in_set()`:

```
select j.ID
from jobs j
where find_in_set('Designer', j.JOBS ) > 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use LIKE statement, and something like `WHERE j.JOBS LIKE "%Designer%"`.