# Find the record that exists in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have a table Record (id, name). Then I have 10 different Method tables in each one there are few sub-methods.

So my tables look like:

One:

```
Record (id, name)
1, abc
2, fgt
3, ght
```

Two:

```
Method A (id, rec_id, meth_name)
1, 3, sub1_metha
2, 3, sub2_metha
3, 2, sub1_metha
4, 1, sub3_metha
....
```

Three:

```
Method Z,(id, rec_id, meth_name)
1, 2, sub1_methz
2, 1, sub4_methz
3, 2, sub3_methz
4, 3, sub1_methz
```

User needs to be able to search by `sub_methods` with either `AND` or `ANY` operand.

I need to create 2 queries:

1. To select all records that have all submethods specified by user.
2. To select all records that have any submethods specified by user.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here (`UNION`, `JOIN`, 10 `SELECT`s)?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: There's `WHERE` and `IN` and/or `FIND_IN_SET` that you can look into, as well as sub-queries.

Comment: Thanks @Fred -ii-, will read about FIND_IN_SET.

Comment: You could make a view with all method tables, and filter on that view.

Comment: See this Q: on SO with the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/23752318/ it may help. If it does, +1 the accepted or other answer given on that page.

Comment: @Gudgip not sure what View is here, but will read about it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have similar information in ten different tables, then your database design is a bit weak. Perhaps you should have only one table for sub_methods and have an additional column to distinguish between them:

```
Method (id, rec_id, type, meth_name)
1, 3, A, sub1_metha
2, 3, A, sub2_metha
3, 2, A, sub1_metha
4, 1, A, sub3_metha
....
1, 2, Z, sub1_methz
2, 1, Z, sub4_methz
3, 2, Z, sub3_methz
4, 3, Z, sub1_methz
```

But with the design you have, you should go ahead and `join` the record table with the `union` of all method tables. Then you can add the user query in the `WHERE` either using `OR` or `AND`, depending on which mode the user wants:

```
SELECT * FROM record
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id, rec_id, 'A' as type, meth_name FROM Method_A
UNION
SELECT id, rec_id, 'Z' as type, meth_name FROM Method_Z
) methods on record.id = methods.rec_id
WHERE ...;
```

**EDIT (alternative solution using a database view):**

As suggested by Gudgip: If you already have your table structure and cannot change it anymore, you can create a `VIEW` to simplify the above query (and potentially other queries). To do this execute this statement once:

```
CREATE VIEW all_methods AS 
SELECT id, rec_id, 'A' as type, meth_name FROM Method_A
UNION
...
UNION
SELECT id, rec_id, 'Z' as type, meth_name FROM Method_Z;
```

As a result you get an "alias" for this construct at database level and your search-query can be written as

```
SELECT * FROM record
INNER JOIN all_methods on record.id = all_methods.rec_id
WHERE ...;
```

Comment: He could create a view out of all his record-tables :-) that might ease up the work.

Comment: @Stefan Winkler thank you! I knew I was overthinking it!