# mysql where in clause with select statement after in clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a  `varchar` field which store values like `2,1` and I am using a query to select the data. The query is this one:

```
SELECT no
FROM c_head          
where id = 9
```

which give output `2,1`

and after that, I use this query

```
SELECT id, item 
FROM c_item 
where type_head IN (SELECT no
FROM c_head          
where id = 9)       
ORDER BY item
```

and its not working its working like  `type_head IN (2)` instead of `type_head IN (2,1)`

but when I simply use hard coded its working

```
 SELECT id, item 
    FROM c_item 
    where type_head IN (2,1)       
    ORDER BY item
```

but its not working with subquery why?

please help me

Comment: So you're saying that `no` is a *text* field that contains the *text* `2,1`?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct its varchar

Comment: possible duplicate of [FIND\_IN\_SET() vs IN()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in)

Comment: The reason it isn't working is because `IN (number, number, ...)` is a list of number values where `IN (text_with_commas)` is comparing to a *single* text value, not a list of numbers.

Comment: so how to store and retrieve data....

Comment: since the subselect returns a literal `2,1`, you're doing `WHERE foo IN ('2,1')`, and the 2,1 is treated as a monolithic value/string, not a CSV value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store comma separated values in column is bad design you should look at [**Database Normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and do normalize your structure by storing all related type_head in a junction table,but if you can't change structure so in mysql you can use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) and join your c_head table,it will select records if it find the value in provided set,IN() will not work for values in set or in comma separated list

```
SELECT i.id, i.item 
FROM c_item i
JOIN c_head h ON(FIND_IN_SET(i.type_head,h.no) > 0)
WHERE h.id = 9
ORDER BY i.item
```

Answer (score 0):

i found my answer

```
SELECT id, item 
FROM c_item 
where  FIND_IN_SET(type_head, (SELECT no
FROM c_head          
where id = {head}))       
ORDER BY item
```

thanks........