# SQL query to match multiple values in a single column

Tags: php, mysql

This dummy table:

```
name | lesson_mode
-------------------

a    | 1,2,3
b    | 2,3 
c    | 2
d    | 3
```

Using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `cc_teacher` WHERE lesson_mode IN (2,3)
```

I get

```
name | lesson_mode
-------------------

b    | 2,3 
c    | 2
d    | 3
```

I am having a problem in search results, my problem is that suppose, in this case we are talking about `lesson_mode` column, I have written the SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `cc_teacher` WHERE lesson_mode IN (2,3)
```

but I didn't get the row in which have `1,2,3`, so please help me. Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Please don't make drastic edits that worsen the quality of your question.

Comment: What type is the `lesson_mode` column? You've tagged your question with both MySQL and SQL Server -- those are different SQL servers, which one are you using?

Comment: @vicvicvic Since he tagged `php` as well, I'm going to say MySQL (not saying that you can't use SQL server with PHP, but I doubt that OP would)

Comment: this should be useful to you i guess : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in

Answer (score 4):

The best help for you is advice to fix your data structure.  You should have a table that is `TeacherLessons` with one row per teacher and one row per lesson.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a "table", not a "string".  And, worse, you are storing numeric ids as character strings.

You *can* do what you want using `find_in_set()`.  It would look like:

```
select *
from cc_teacher
where find_in_set(2, lesson_mode) > 0 or
      find_in_set(3, lesson_mode) > 0;
```

But my main advice is for your to fix our database structure by introducing a junction table.

Comment: thanks for your answers but one more issue occured if i have multople columns like same as lesson_mode in that time case what can i do

Comment: @ganesh . . . You would have multiple junction tables, one for each list.  Also, you can ask another question, because this question is specifically about one column.

Comment: @ganesh Add more where conditions, or actually follow good advice and take Gordon's first suggestion.

Comment: @sjagr . . . This *is* MySQL specific.  The generic approach would use `like`, but there is no reason to use that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Apologies, I was thrown off the scent when you said "SQL has a..."