# How to SELECT multiple tags

Tags: php, mysql

table1(posts)

```
[pid - ptitle - pcontent - ptags]
[1 - PHPCourse - Lorem - PHP,MYSQL,PDO]
```

table2(tags)

```
[tag_id, tag_name]
[1      -      PHP]
[2     -     MYSQL]
[3      -      PDO]
```

What is the best way to relate these two tables?
i checked the 3 tables way  where i make a 3rd table

table3(posts_tags)

```
[pid  -  tag_id]
[1    -       1]
[1    -       2]
[1    -       3]
```

But people said that this is bad for SELECT query, Even tho i was going to use it like this

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id = $pid
```

but i saw people using something called inner join without even mentioning table3 in the code, And i couldn't understand it, So how can i do it properly?

Comment: Take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below code.

table1(posts)

```
[pid - ptitle - pcontent ]
[1 - PHPCourse - Lorem]
[1 - PHPCourse - Lorem]
```

table2(tags)

```
[tag_id, tag_name]
[1      -      PHP]
[2     -     MYSQL]
[3      -      PDO]
```

table3(posts_tags)

```
[pid  -  tag_id]
[1    -       1]
[1    -       2]
[1    -       3]

select * from posts 
inner join posts_tags at posts.pid = posts_tags.pid
inner join tags at tags.tag_id = post_tags.tag_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table design approach looks good.
Also, wordpress and drupal are using similar approach. 
If you want to know more, please google "wordpress taxonomy or drupal taxonomy".
Download their source and analyze DB schema will help you.

(Not sure how it is possible to fetch data without using posts_tags...)
Here is my table schema and query.

**posts**

```
id, title, content
1,  foo,   bar
2,  foo2,  bar2
```

**tags**

```
id, name
1,  tag1
2,  tag2
3,  tag3
4,  tag4
```

**posts_tags**

```
pid, tid
1,   1
1,   2
1,   3
2,   1
2,   2
2,   4
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.content, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as ptags 
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt ON (p.id = pt.pid)
INNER JOIN tags t ON (t.id = pt.tid)
/* WHERE p.id = 1 */
GROUP BY p.id
```

**RESULT**

```
id  title  content  ptags
1   foo    bar      tag1,tag2,tag3
2   foo2   bar2     tag1,tag2,tag4
```

As you separated posts and tags tables, anytime your can add or remove tags features with adding or removing tags,posts_tags.