# MySQL PHP - Search to see if column contains one of a list of variables

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so this is a little hard to explain but I have something like this:

```
$yourScripts = 777,1337, -- My variable

$yourData = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM scriptlog WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$yourScripts', scriptid)") -- My query
```

My scriptlog table looks like this:

```
scriptid | other stuff
-----------------------
1337     | xxxxxxx
456      | xxxxxxx
777      | xxxxxxx
```

How can I get my query to return the rows that have the correct scriptid? Currently it returns nothing.

I have also tried this but it also returns nothing:

```
$yourData = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM scriptlog WHERE scriptid LIKE '%{$yourScripts}%'")
```

Comment: Some reading for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in

Comment: You have the arguments to `FIND_IN_SET` backwards. Otherwise it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma-separated string is the second argument to `FIND_IN_SET`, not the first, so it should be:

```
$yourData = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM scriptlog WHERE FIND_IN_SET(scriptid, '$yourScripts')");
```

You could also use `IN()` which is better because it can use the index.

```
$yourData = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM scriptlog WHERE scriptid IN ($yourScripts)");
```

If `$yourScripts` is coming from the user, make sure you sanitize it first before substituting into the SQL -- it should only be integers.

Comment: Thank you for this. $yourScripts actually comes from another mySQL query, but I was sure to sanitize all user inputs just in case Thanks :)

Comment: If it comes from another query, why don't you just join the tables in a single query, instead of turning it into a string.