# The difference between find_in_set() sql and whereIn laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have an eloquent query in Laravel that looks something like this:

```
return $query->with('status', 'bank')
             ->whereHas('status', function (Builder $builder) {
    return $builder->whereIn('bank_status', ['MANUAL', 'VALIDATED,ACTIVATED']);
});
```

I am looking for any possible values that will match the given: `['MANUAL', 'VALIDATED,ACTIVATED']` I do have comma seperated values .

I am not sure if its the right choice to use `whereIn` or should I go with rawsql `find_in_set()`   which is the best to use in this case ?

If anyone has an answer would be nice to convert my query builder using `find_in_set()` thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have comma separated values in your column you should use `find_in_set()` rather than `in`. If your column row has following value `'VALIDATED,ACTIVATED'` and you will search for `ACTIVATED` using `IN` it will fail and return no rows.

```
return $query
    ->with('status', 'bank')
    ->whereHas('status', function (Builder $builder) use ($needle){
        return $builder->whereRaw('FIND_IN_SET(?, bank_status)', [$needle]);
});
```

More about your question - [FIND_IN_SET() vs IN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in)

Comment: Yeah sounds just about right so $needle in this case are my values that I will look for like ['ACTIVATED,VALIDATED' , 'SEND]

Comment: Exactly, but if you want to pass an array, then you might want to change `[$needle]` to `$needle` and also change variable name to `$params` for better naming.

Answer (score 0):

try this type of query in laravel

```
$search =  VALIDATED;

->whereRaw("find_in_set('".$search."',MANUAL)")
```

Comment: Basically I want to get all the data from db where status is MANUAL OR VALIDATED,ACTIVATED or smth else.