# can i use IN operator in MYSQ ON Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have this sample mysql statement

```
SELECT f.* FROM foo f
INNER JOIN bar b ON b.id IN(f.field_containing_values_separated_by_comma)
WHERE b.id IN (1,2,3)
```

sample values of (varchar)f.field_containing_values_separated_by_comma
would be

```
'1,3,5'
'2,5,7'
'10,9'
'4,5'
```

my expected results would be to fetch the foo records of this f.field_containing_values_separated_by_comma

```
'1,3,5'
'2,5,7'
```

any ideas why im not getting it? or where there be any other better ways of doing this? im using PHP as back end by the way

Regards

Comment: You should fix(normalize) your schema

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the FIND_IN_SET function like this:

```
select distinct foo.* from foo cross join bar
WHERE bar.id IN(1,2) and FIND_IN_SET(foo.id, bar.field_containing_values_separated_by_comma)
```

Documention [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)