# IN operator doesn't return any results in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following query:

```
SELECT p.*
        FROM property p
        INNER JOIN property_meta pm ON p.id = pm.property_id 
        WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE concat("%", :title, "%") AND p.deleted = :deleted AND ((pm.meta_key = :area_key AND pm.meta_value IN (:area_value)) )  GROUP BY p.id
```

which is executed using the following binding parameters:

```
$bind[':title'] = '';
$bind[':deleted'] = 0;
$bind[':area_key'] = 'property_area';
$bind[':area_value'] = '1217, 1270';

$sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($bind);
return $sth->fetchAll();
```

the problem is that I doesn't get any result, but the most weird thing is that if I execute the query using `PhpMyAdmin` console, I correctly get the results.

is there any mistake I did?

**Table structure**

the `property` table have the following structure:

```
| id | title | deleted
  1     test    0
  2     test2   0
```

and `property_meta` have this structure:

```
| id | property_id | meta_key        | meta_value  
  1       1           property_area      1217
  4       2           property_area      1270
```

Comment: Have you set it to show errors? add  `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` in the initialisation see [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: @akaBase yep this option is on, unfortunately I didn't get any errors, I just reiceve an empty result

Comment: IN won't work with a CSV string, you may be able to use FIND_IN_SET - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in

Comment: You should check the `$sth->execute($bind)`  in an if/else statement and and if its false there is an error and you can then get that message using `$sth->errorInfo()`

Comment: The comment of @NigelRen has pointed me in the right direction, most probably I need to convert the values within `IN` operator in different parameters, that's why is not working

Comment: If there really are no errors, then it's not a PDO, but an SQL problem. So in that case you'll have to share the db structure (with a little sample data to see what's expected).

Comment: @El_Vanja please, check my example in the updated question, as I said using the same query all is working in PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: @vrijdenker should I iterate over each values and binding it?

Comment: I think so. I think the first answer in that post explains how to do it. However, I think the answer below (Gihan's answer) would work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your query

1. `LIKE concat("%", :title, "%")`

Instead, you should use as below

```
LIKE :title
...
$bind[':title'] = '%' . $title . '%';
```

2. `pm.meta_value IN (:area_value)`

PDO doesn't support binding values for IN clause. Instead, you should use as below

```
pm.meta_value IN ($areaValue)
```

You'll have to properly sanitize `$areaValue` and it should not be empty.

Comment: what about if `$areaValue` have this content: `Array
(
    [0] => 1213
    [1] => 1270
)`

Comment: It has to be a CSV string as you do in plain SQL. You can do `implode(',' $array)`. Make sure $array is not empty.

Comment: 1. what's wrong with `LIKE concat("%", :title, "%")`?

Comment: 2. Ever heard of SQL injections?