# mysql select query within a array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi guys I have this situation

```
tabperfil
ta

bperfil.Cidade_Id -> values = 12,34,645,21
```

then I have a `$id = 12`

so I'm try to do this query

```
select * from tabperfil limit 0,5
```

but with a condiction for get the values of `Cidade_Id` and check with `$id`

if was a reverse situation I know

```
select * from tabperfil WHERE Cidade_Id IN ($id)
```

so how do something to works like this

```
select * from tabperfil WHERE ($id) in Cidade_Id
```

Comment: If you can't use proper grammar, why should we answer your question?

Comment: Have a look at mysql regular expression... you're going to be looking for scenarios where id matches the string up to the first comma, immediately follows a comma and ends with a comma, or where it follows a comma and ends the line.

Comment: nobody is perfect my friend, i m not a english expert but i try... if u can use, congrat's . i m learning

Comment: @blake305 There are a lot of non-native English speaking individuals here. Requiring proper grammar before answering a question would eliminate a lot of the help that could be provided.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont get it, can you please explain it more. What do you actually want, what is the code yo ugot, what is the problem

Comment: @blake305 - I don't think that's fair. Not everyone is a native English speaker.

Comment: @jprofitt It was almost unreadable before I edited it.

Comment: @JamesAllardice It was almost unreadable before I edited it.

Comment: So what is the difference you expect Cidade_Id IN ($id)
 and ($id) in Cidade_Id  . please explain why you trying the second one!!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql check if numbers are in a comma separated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674011/mysql-check-if-numbers-are-in-a-comma-separated-list)

Comment: @blake305 I was the last to approve your edit, so I saw it before it went through.

Comment: @blake305 - Your edits consisted of a few capitalisations and a bit of missing code formatting. I would hardly say it was "unreadable". As the OP said in his comment, at least he's learning. These comments will likely get removed if we carry on like this, so let's leave it at that.

Comment: @zod my english like blake305 says not good, so maybe you can understand. i have a table citys there is a array (1,23,45) when people go to the website they select a city and i set the cookie to the city id like 1 - then i want to select on db the results only if is in table city... did u get?

Answer (score 5):

`WHERE FIND_IN_SET($id, Cidade_Id) > 0`

But you should really normalize your database. Having comma-seperated values in 1 column is asking for trouble.

Comment: I really think that everyone who works with databases, or at least the programming of database applications, should know how to normalize a database, and not only know it, but also do it.

Comment: ok, i did this - maybe not right away but works

citys => (1,3,5,7)
$id = 1

   $sql "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (citys LIKE '$id,%' or citys LIKE '%,$id,%' OR citys LIKE '%,$id')";

thanks

Comment: Don't do that. Change your database layout so you don't have a column with comma-separated values anymore if possible.