# Trouble with MySQL WHERE clause and delimited strings

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, where-clause

I have a database table which stores products.  Each product can have multiple colours.  Each colour is represented by its ID rather than a textual description like 'Red', 'Yellow', etc. When the `$_POST['colour']` array is imploded into a string (delimited by commas) it is then stored in the table:

```
product_id | colour
----------------------
1          | 1,2
2          | 10
3          | 7,9
```

Recently I've tried to create a search form which could select a number of colours and search the database table to see if there are any products which contain at least one of the colours in the search array.  So if a visitor wanted to see products for colours 1 and 9, I need to search the 'colour' column for these two values.

I can't use `WHERE colour IN (1,9)` because I think that only works if you have one value in the column (rather than a delimited array of multiple values).  Nor can I use `WHERE colour LIKE 1 OR WHERE colour LIKE 9` because it would return products which have a colour ID of 10 or 11 or 12, etc.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql select query within a array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840232/mysql-select-query-within-a-array)

Comment: [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: What is the definition of your colour column?

Comment: @Wrikken - that solution was perfect, thank you.

Comment: @AdrianCornish what do you mean by 'definition'?

Comment: @Jamie how is the column defined in the CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: It was something like VARCHAR(100) but now I've deleted the column and normalized the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This table need to be normalized if you wanna get good performance, create a productColor table with a one-to-many relation with the product table.**

That being said:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE Colour LIKE '%,1,%' OR Colour LIKE '1,% OR COLOUR LIKE '%,1'
   OR Colour LIKE '%,9,%' OR Colour LIKE '9,% OR COLOUR LIKE '%,9'
```

Comment: +1 Just stressing the point that this table *really* needs to be normalized.

Comment: Thanks - I've normalized the table now and refactored my code :)

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the table.

In the mean time, you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 1, Colour )
   OR FIND_IN_SET( 9, Colour )           --- etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an association table for products and colors, rather than storing multiple vales in a single column. Like assocProductsColors with col for productId and colorId include a Id col as the key for the table

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the comments you already have, I'd suggest modifying your database to have:

```
product_id | colour
----------------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 10
3          | 7
3          | 9
```

However, you could also use [MySQL Regex Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html), in particular `RLIKE` ("regex like") to do this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE Colour RLIKE '[[:<:]][19][[:>:]]'
```

The regular expression `[[:<:]][19][[:>:]]` means "match a 1 or a 9 (`[19]`), where it's a *whole word*". The `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` mean "word boundary", so the given pattern will only match the 1 or 9 if it's an entire word on its own, and not if it's part of another number.