# Show the row if the id is in the field separated with commas

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql check if numbers are in a comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674011/mysql-check-if-numbers-are-in-a-comma-separated-list)

> Note: Please don't tell me to normalize my database

Ok so what I need is fetch only rows if the id is present in another table which are comma separated...But am having no idea how to select

`table1`

```
script_id | name | user_id
+-------------------------+
   33       demo    256
```

`table2`

```
has_access| name |user_id
+-------------------------+
 33,34,56   demo    256
```

So I want the row to return from `table1` only if the id exists inside the `table2` `has_access` column, moreover I need exact, so if the ID gets 33, or 333 should be different...I need the exact value match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql has `FIND_IN_SET` function for exactly this kind of data:

```
.... WHERE find_in_set(table1.script_id,table2.has_access)
```

But you'd better <strike>norma</strike> sorry, couldn't resist.

Answer (score 2):

Please, don't tell us what to tell you.

Read this first: **[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)**
Short answer: **Yes, it's really that bad.**

And the similar: **[Is using multiple foreign keys separated by commas wrong, and if so, why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17808/is-using-multiple-foreign-keys-separated-by-commas-wrong-and-if-so-why)**
Short answer: **Yes, it's very, very wrong.**

**Normalize your database.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way:

```
select *
from table1
where concat(',', has_access, ',') like concat('%,', YOURIDTOTEST, ',%')
```

This delimits each value with a comma (the separator).  It then puts a comma at the beginning and end of the list and matches when the second is "like" the first.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) mysql function (I'm assuming that's what you're using since it's what the post was tagged with).  I haven't tried it, but since your `has_access` column is a string, you should be matching strings and something like 333 would not be a match for 33.

Answer (score 0):

select table1.* from table1 join table2 on (
 table2.has_access = table1.script_id
 or table2.has_access like concat(table1.script_id, ',%')
 or table2.has_access like concat('%,', table1.script_id, ',%')
 or table2.has_access like concat('%,', table1.script_id)
)

I think I covered all the cases.