# MySql find a value in a comma separated set

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like, find-in-set

I have values stored like this in a field `1,255,230,265`.

Is there a function in MySQL that will give me the second value in that string? In this case it'll be `255`.

I tried using `locate`, but that does not seem to be meant for this.

Comment: Do you want second value or a specific value no matter at what location? That makes a huge difference in approach you should follow

Comment: @BhavikShah I want only the second value in any given set. In this case its 255

Comment: This link might be useful: https://www.giannistsakiris.com/2015/01/23/mysql-select-the-n-th-element-from-a-delimiter-separated-value-set/

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
select  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field_name,',',2),",",-1)  from table_name
```

Comment: The only caveat is that `field_name` should have at least 2 values. If it has only one value, then that value is returned. For eg: `select substring_index( substring_index( 'a', ',', 2), ',', -1)` returns `a`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use SUBSTRING_INDEX() function.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,',',2),',',-1)
FROM yourTable.
```

This grabs everything infront of the second comma, then grabs everything after the last comma (-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select * from Table1 where ',' + Nos+ ',' like '%,255,%'
```

Refer:

[MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

[mysql check if numbers are in a comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674011/mysql-check-if-numbers-are-in-a-comma-separated-list)

Comment: I need the number 255 to be output. I.E the second value in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(255, columnName)
```

**OR**

Use **LIKE** operator

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
WHERE CONCAT(',', columnName, ',') LIKE '%,255,%'
```