# php select number in string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have query like this

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id ='1'`

but in column id store data like this

```
array (size=2)
   0 => string '1' (length=1)
   'id' => string '1' (length=1)
array (size=2)
   0 => string '1,2' (length=3)
   'id' => string '1,2' (length=3)
array (size=2)
   0 => string '1,2,3' (length=5)
  'id' => string '1,2,3'
```

Result of my query is show only 1 row but what I need is show every row that has value `1` in it.

plz help me with it

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql check if numbers are in a comma separated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674011/mysql-check-if-numbers-are-in-a-comma-separated-list)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `LIKE %%` to achieve this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE '%1%'
```

Comment: I need real value not probably value

Answer (score 0):

Pull from the table as the current data, then:

```
 $NewArr = array();
 foreach ($Array as $values){
      $NewArr[] = (int) @values;

 }
```