# Select where an column with comma separated values contains an ID

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have two tables: `tbl_post` and `tbl_tags`.

In `tbl_post`, the field `tags` contains *IDs* from `tbl_tags` as an array.
Example: `'1,3,15,20'` or `'4,15,6,21'`

I want to select records from `tbl_post` whose field `tags` contains an ID from `tbl_tags` (Example: '15').

How can I do this?

Comment: You should change your schema if you can. It's a bad idea to have comma-separated values in a column, because it makes queries awkward.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_post WHERE tbl_post.tags LIKE '%15%';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_post WHERE Contains(tbl_post.tags, '15');
```

As per your comment, you could try this

```
DECLARE @id INT = 15
DECLARE @stringId VARCHAR(50) = CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(50))

SELECT * 
FROM tbl_post 
WHERE tbl_post.tags = @stringId -- When there is only 1 id in the table
OR tbl_post.tags LIKE @stringId + ',%' -- When the id is the first one
OR tbl_post.tags LIKE '%,' + @stringId + ',%' -- When the id is in the middle
OR tbl_post.tags LIKE '%,' + @stringId -- When the id is at the end
```

[Referenced from this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278789/sql-server-check-if-number-is-in-comma-separated-list)

Comment: what if `tags` is `1,3,154`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I've update the answer to handle this, but really you need a very good reason for using a using a comma separated list value over an efficiently designed DB Schema.

Comment: Oh, I agree. I'm not OP, by the way. Just noticed a bug. You could also do something like `where (',' + tbl_post.tags + ',') like '%,15,%'` instead of the three separate clauses.

Comment: This is non-standard SQL. Please mention the DBMS for which this is working (the question so far is not marked with any specific DBMS product)

Comment: Hello bros., I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

working query for all cases :

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_post` WHERE find_in_set('15',tbl_post.tags)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_post` WHERE find_in_set('15',tbl_post.tags) <> 0
```