# SQL Comma delimeter list replace each value with single qoutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, csv

I am currently using sql server 2014

I have a sql column which could contain the following values

```
user_email
--------------------------------------------
fred.bloggs@abc.co.uk
joe.bloggs@abc.co.uk
sally.bloggs@abc.co.uk;fred.bloggs@abc.co.uk
```

I need to select columns and build a where clause

so `where user_email like '%sally.bloggs@abc.co.uk%'` will select the 3rd row, but if I was to do `user_email like '%lly.bloggs@abc.co.uk%'` it would not select the 3rd row.

Hopefully this makes sense?

I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Not storing delimited data is the *real* solution here. Fix your design, fix the problem.

Comment: Its a legacy app, I really don't have a choice.

Comment: Legacy applications have to be updated at some point. What better time to start than now?

Comment: `';' + user_email + ';' LIKE '%;lly.bloggs@abc.co.uk;%'`

Comment: I couldn't understand your statement *"if I was to do user_email like `'%lly.bloggs@abc.co.uk%'` it would not select the 3rd row"* - if you do that it WILL select the 3rd row?

Comment: @CaiusJard - The Op wants it to Not match, because `lly` has a relation called `sally`, but they don't have the same email address, so they shouldn't match.  *(The wild card matching being used to overcome the bad design of using `;` delimitered emails, but otherwise desiring exact matches only.)*

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the cost of improving the data structure is indeed higher than benefit it would yield, leading to the desire to use a workaround.

Just be careful, by using a workaround you accrue technical debt:
- More things to go wrong more easily in the future

For a quick win, just force the strings you're comparing to start and end with the delimiter being used...

```
';' + user_email + ';' LIKE '%;' + 'lly.bloggs@abc.co.uk' + ';%'
```

Comment: I'm not *really* sure why we needed another duplicate of "how to split a delimited string in SQL Server". :/

Comment: @larnu : The answer you linked was about splitting one row in to several rows, which is a heavy-weight solution to a light-weight problem.  In order to be of help to the OP I believe that providing a useful light-weight approach to his personal scenario is of benefit.  (feel free to close the question again, I'm not chasing rep)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot lock this again, but this is does feel like a duplicate of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33278978/2029983) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20525923/2029983).

Comment: Ye.. Just concerned with all the coronatenation going on that that `... + 'lly.bloggs@abc.co.uk' + ...` would straight up become `... + '{loginNameTextBox.Text}' + ...`

Comment: @CaiusJard - Do Not Edit My Answers