# MYSQL WHERE IN explode array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a users table with fields

```
(id, name, email, companies)
```

and data as:

```
(1, 'Dave', 'dave@test.com', '1,3')
(2, 'Jake', 'jake@test.com', '2,3')
(3, 'Peter', 'peter@test.com', '1,2')
```

Each user can access the companies in their profile. The problem I have is to select the relevant users for a specific company.

For example, I want the users fro company 2, so the result should be `'Jake'` and `'Peter'`. Getting the result in PHP is pretty easy, just do a normal query to the user's table and explode the companies and check if the company exists. Is there a way to do it in MYSQL?

I've tried `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE companies IN (???)` but I can't get my head around how to explode the companies in MYSQL.

Comment: i think you need `FIND_IN_SET()`

Comment: tryBake it is mysqli

Comment: Suggestion. Normalise your schema. Normally I (personally) would expect company to be it's own table, and if a user can be in multiple companies, then have a link table to join them up.

Comment: either you have to store separate company id in `number` field or use => https://stackoverflow.com/a/2674209/6309457

Comment: Don't store data like this. You'll be able to get away this time but this will make things a lot harder. Normalize your database.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want the users of company 2.

`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE find_in_set('2', companies)` will work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked exactly the way I needed it to work.