# Mysql IN clause with multiple values in string field

Tags: mysql

I have a field that contains a string values like this: '1,2,3,4'

I want to bring it if contains the number 2,4. But its not working.
I have try this:

```
SELECT field IN (2,4)
```

and this:

```
select find_in_set('2,4', field)
```

Comment: Now you see why putting comma delimited data in a MySQL cell is such a bad idea and breaks all sorts of Normalisation rules

Answer (score 1):

As `find_in_set()` will only find one string within another, you will have to use many `find_in_set` searches. Also this is because if you have `1,2,3,4` but want to find `1 and 3` or `1 and 4` you cannot make a finder string to do that.

So to find 1 and 3 in `1,2,3,4` use

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
where find_in_set('1', COL)
AND find_in_set('3', COL);
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
WHERE banana IN ('apple', 'banana', 'coconut')
WHERE 3 IN (2,3,6,8,90)
```

source : [mysql check if numbers are in a comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674011/mysql-check-if-numbers-are-in-a-comma-separated-list)